# Can't compile project when using modules in multiple files: "imports can only refer to extern crate names passed with --extern"

Tags: module, rust

I have *main.rs* and *bear.rs* under the *src* directory. Every time I compile, the compiler points to [E0658](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/error-index.html#E0658). I've read the docs for E0658, and it tells me that this is an unstable feature.

*main.rs*

```
mod bear;

use bear::factory::make_bear;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let bear = make_bear();
}
```

*bear.rs*

```
pub mod factory {
    pub fn make_bear() -> Bear {
        // code to instantiate Bear struct.
    }    
}
```

When I compile this code I get this from the compiler:

```
error[E0658]: imports can only refer to extern crate names passed with `--extern` on stable channel (see issue #53130)
  --> src/main.rs:1:5
   |
1  |   use bear::factory::make_bear;
   |       ^^^^
...
8  | / mod bear {
9  | |     pub mod factory {
10 | |         pub fn make_bear() -> Bear {
11 | |             // code to instantiate Bear struct.
12 | |         }
13 | |     }
14 | | }
   | |_- not an extern crate passed with `--extern`
   |
```

Do I have to wait for consensus among the  Rust community, or is there something I can do right now besides the inconvenient suggestion in the docs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change

```
use bear::factory::make_bear;
```

to

```
use crate::bear::factory::make_bear;
```

This was a change [in the 2018 edition of Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/module-system/path-clarity.html). I won't recreate everything on this page, but I can say that the motivation for this change is twofold, one is to stop requiring the `extern crate bear;` directives, while also removing the ambiguities that might arise in the case that you have both a local module name `bear` and also a dependency on an external crate also named `bear`.

Comment: Congratulations on 10k.